# Python datetime randomly breaking

Tags: python, datetime

This isn't the first time this has happened to me so now I'm looking for an answer because I'm completely stumped.

I have code running in a production environment for over 3 months now and it worked absolutely fine, then out of no where I started to get errors in python.

```
'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'

Exception Value:    
'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
Exception Location: /admin/views/create.py in process, line 114

/admin/views/create.py in process
            order = Orders(uid=0, accepted=0, canview='', files=0, date=datetime.date.today(), due=dueDate,
```

As you can see, I'm using the following which works absolutely fine from the python shell:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today()
>>> datetime.date(2011, 9, 27)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is importing `datetime.datetime` somewhere, instead of just `datetime`, e.g. `from datetime import datetime`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.date.today()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Comment: not the case.. just searched for "datetime.datetime" on the page and got nothing.  Like i said, it was working fine for 3 months with no changes..

Comment: You can say "not the case" if you like, but I've proved it above.

Comment: is it possible that datetime is being used from another class that I'm importing?

Comment: that's exactly what happened.. "from admin.helpers.functions import *" had "from datetime import date,datetime".  I didn't think those carried over like that.  Good to know and rather odd.

Comment: that's why you should not use `from . import *`

Comment: yeah, i understand that.  But that page has ~40 helper functions and I typically use 20 of them on a regular basis.  What I don't get is why my code worked in the first place and then that randomly became an issue, because those pages of code have been untouched for quite some time.

Comment: That's what your VCS should be able to tell you.

Comment: @Chris That's why you should just import the package: `from foo.bar import helpers/ helper.method()/ helper.other_method()`

Answer (score 4):

```
--> from datetime import datetime
--> datetime.date.today()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Either your `datetime` import is being overridden by a subsequent import, or some other code is injecting a different `datetime` into your module.

**Update**

`from ... import *` is meant to populate the current namespace with whatever is in `...` -- not strange at all.  Presumably you have those functions in `admin.helpers.functions` for that very purpose.